# custom action submitting multiple forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, custom-routes

So I have this structure of application: a `Game` model which has many `Allies` and many `Enemies`.

I want to create a custom action for `Game` dedicated to create and submit enemies and allies.
So in the view I will have 2 fields_for that you can submit at the same time.

I have never created custom routes and actions or submitted 2 children forms in the same page.

Anyone know how I could do this ? Thanks

Comment: Do you have `Player` model? if so what is the association between `Game` and `Player`

Comment: I do not have a Player model. Game has_many :allies and has_many: enemies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**routes.rb**

```
#this route shows the form
get 'create-players/:id', to 'game#new_players', as: :new_players
# this route recieves the form post submission
post 'create-players/:id', to 'game#create_players', as: :create_players
```

app/controllers/game_controller.rb:

```
def new_players
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
end

def create_players
  #do whatever you want with the params passed from the form like
  @allies = Ally.create(game_id: params[:id], name: params[:ally_fields][:name])
  @enemies = Enemy.create(game_id: params[:id], name: params[:enemy_fields][:name])
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
end
```

app/views/game/new_players.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag(create_players_paths, @game.id), method: 'POST') do %>
  <% #...fields you have on models, perhaps %>
  <% fields_for :ally_fields do |f|
    <%= f.text_field :name, nil, placeholder: "Ally name", required: true
  <% end % >
  <% fields_for :enemy_fields do |f|
    <%= f.text_field :name, nil, placeholder: "Enemy name", required: true
  <% end % >
  <%= submit_tag "create players", class: "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/game/create_players.html.erb:

```
   <h1> Woah an allie and an enemy have been added to game <%= @game.id %></h1>
   <p> Lets see some blood!</p>
```

Of course, you should enforce verifications on the input and before processing the post submission. Usually you'll want to use established relationships between objects, so that you can do on the view `@model = Modelname.new` then, `form_for @object` and have validations and error messages accessible in a much cleaner way.

Comment: Had to change `post 'create-players/:id', to 'game#create_players', as: :create_players` to `get 'create-players/:id', to: 'games#create_players', as: :create_players` to make it work but submit button won't work now though

Comment: Do I need 2 routes ?

Comment: @LRP wrote a bit more explaining

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for